# django-allauth with SSL : "DoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/"

Tags: django, ssl, django-allauth

I'm testing my django (1.6.5) app in localhost. I use django-allauth and without ssl everything was ok.

I installed django-sslserver and change as follows:

Settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'    # allauth

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
```

Api Google Console

```
REDIRECT URIS : http://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
                https://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

When I logged in with my google account, I accepted the authorization, but when it's redirected back to my app, shows the error:

```
DoesNotExist at /accounts/google/login/callback/
User matching query does not exist.
Request URL:    https://localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/?state=PwKj3DsvzmNp&code=4/16ttwvGn7SIZKyHWZ9sSy8YOx7sg.4t9M4AcGcoEfoiIBeO6P2m9E6KmpkAI

allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py in _login_social_account

def _login_social_account(request, sociallogin):
**return perform_login(request, sociallogin.account.user, ...**
                     email_verification=app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                     redirect_url=sociallogin.get_redirect_url(request),
                     signal_kwargs={"sociallogin": sociallogin})
```

The error is in the return line. 
Can you help me? Thanks! :)